# Access original edit form

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, custom-form, edit-form

I have a list with custom new and edit forms. Some fields are entered onto the New form but then cannot be edited using the Edit form. A user has made a mistake on the New form and needs this field amending but cannot access it. Is there a way to use the original Edit form to edit this list item and update the field? I don't want to re-attach the original Edit form and give other users (albeit temporary) accesss to it

Edit - The custom forms were created in SharePoint Designer

Answer (score 0):

On the List/Library Tab, you'll see a button to the far right called "Modify Form Web Parts".  Clicking on this will give you access to the default three forms: -
1 - Default New Form
2 - Default Display Form
3 - Default Edit Form

Click on the Edit Form and it'll load the page.  On the URL, delete everything after the EditForm.aspx? and add ID=.

If you send that link to the user, it'll enable him to edit the item with the original form.

Comment: Where do I find the "Modify Form Web Parts" buttons? Have you a screenshot?

Comment: On the list, click the List Tab, this'll load a new ribbon. Look to the far right, next to the List Settings and you should see them there.

Comment: Either I'm looking in the wrong place or I don't have access to this. Do you need a lot of admin rights to access this?

Comment: When I tried Google-ing this the only hits had screenshots from 2010, are you sure you can do this in 2007?